# What are the benefits (if any) of using AutoMapper's IMappingEngine with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm relatively new to AutoMapper (but love it already) and have been declaring my mapping profiles by using `Mapper.CreateMap<T,T>()` via a static method called in `Global.asax.cs`.

However, after reading more about AutoMapper I've also noticed the option of injecting the `IMapperEngine` interface using an IoC container (StructureMap in my case) and DI, leading me to wonder what (if any) additional benefits this would present me **other than those gained when using Dependency Injection** (mocking, inversion of control, etc).

For instance, does the use of IMapperEngine defer the loading of profiles until they're used or am I completely off the mark?

Comment: I suspect (not having used AutoMapper) that this exists to allow you to dependancy inject your dependancy injection framework, so that you can mock it out, to test your tests.
(So I heard you liked some DI so i put some DI in your DI, so you can test your tests)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm wondering what other benefits it might bring than those gained by using DI. I have updated my question to make it a little clearer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm relatively new to AutoMapper (but love it already) and have been
>   declaring my mapping profiles by using Mapper.Map via a static method
>   called in Global.asax.cs.

I hope you are not doing that. The `Mapper.Map` method is used to perform the actual mapping between object instances. What you should be doing in your `Global.asax.cs` is define your mappings using the `Mapper.CreateMap` static method.

Now as far as your question about the `IMapperEngine` interface is concerned, it is good practice to always work with abstractions in your code. In your controller actions you will no longer be hardcoding static method calls to `Mapper.Map` but instead you will be using the abstraction that you could mock in your unit test. No other noticeable benefits.

Using this interface is not deferring anything. If you injected the concrete `Mapper.Engine` instance then all you are doing when you are calling the `IMapperEngine.Map` method is calling the underlying `Mapper.Engine.Map` method.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say Mapper.CreateMap (I've been writing Mapper.Map far too much as you can probably tell by this question ;) Thank you for your clarification of IMappingEngine.